# Nullable list in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a multi tier set of objects in a model with parent child relationships.  See code below:

```
    public class TracksCollectionsPagesModel : List<TracksModel>
{


}


public class TracksModel : List<CollectionModel>
{
    public Guid? TrackID { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string TrackDescription { get; set; }
    //public List<CollectionModel> Collections { get; set; }


}

public class CollectionModel : List<PagesModel>
{
    public Guid? CollectionID { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public string CollectionDescription { get; set; }
    //public List<PagesModel> Pages { get; set; }


}

public class PagesModel : List<ContentItemsModel>
{
    public Guid? PageID { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string PageDescription { get; set; }
    //public List<ContentItemsModel> ContentItems { get; set; }

}

public class ContentItemsModel 
{
    public Guid? ContentItemID { get; set; }
    public string ContentItemName { get; set; }
    public string ContentItemDescription { get; set; }

}
```

I have a partial view that allows you to create "tracks" the highest level object with a sub list of collections, and sub lists below that until you get to a raw content item.  However when I create this partial view and submit data into it, the model always appears null in the controller.  This ususally occurs when I try to submit a model that has improper bindings.

```
@model JustLMS.Services.Models.Content.TracksModel



@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTrack", "Content", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="AddTrackForm"}))
{
<div id="showErrorMessage"></div>
Model.TrackID = Guid.NewGuid();
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TrackID)
<table>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TrackName)    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrackName, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TrackName)
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TrackDescription)     </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrackDescription, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TrackDescription)
</td>
</tr>

</table>


var collections = new List<JustLMS.Services.Models.Content.CollectionModel>();
Model.Collections = collections;
Model.Collections.Add(new JustLMS.Services.Models.Content.CollectionModel());


@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Collections)





}
```

The partial only really needs to send data about a track, since anything below that will be configured on a different screen.  Do I need to somehow initialize all the sub classes below it to make this a valid model binding?  Or is there someway I can create a nullable list (throwing an error saying you can't have nullable lists in a model).  Should I create a seperate model just for adding tracks with this partial?  Should I separate all these levels of the model into different models?  Just trying to figure out a) how I can get this to work and b) what is the best practice for doing what I am trying to do?  Feel free to ask questions if I didn't explain clearly enough.

Update:

Here is my controller code, the tracksmodel parameter is what is coming in as null

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddTrack(TracksModel model)
    {


        bool isSuccess;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            isSuccess = _service.AddTrack((TracksModel)model);
            if (isSuccess == true)
            {
                return Json(new { result = isSuccess, responseText = "Track added!" });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { result = isSuccess, responseText = "An error ocurred, please review your data for accuracy or contact your administrator.  " });
            }

        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
            return Json(new { result = isSuccess, responseText = "Unable to save track to database, please review your data for accurary." });
        }
    }
```

Update: Added Javascript at commentors request.

```
        // modal for adding Tracks
    $('#AddNewTrack').click(function () {
        $('#AddNewTrackModal').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
            width: 500,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add Track Form',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("AddTrack")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Add Track": function () {
                    addTrackInfo();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });




    function addTrackInfo() {

        alert($("#AddTrackForm").serialize());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddTrack")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#AddTrackForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.result) {
                    $(':input', '#AddTrackForm')
                        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                        .val('')
                        .removeAttr('checked')
                        .removeAttr('selected');
                    alert(data.responseText);
                    $('#AddEntityModal').dialog("close");
                    window.location = "@Url.Action("Tracks")";
                } else {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                    $('#AddEntityModal').dialog("close");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Quick note, I have tried removing hidden from the .not() and it still is null.

Comment: Why do your classes inherit from a base class only to then have an instance of that base class as a property?

Comment: I commented those out, for some reason it made sense to me when I was doing the model design initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just editing the `TracksModel` portion, then you don't need to worry about any of the collections in your *view*, i.e. you don't need to creating form fields and worry about posting those back.

If you're creating a new `TracksModel`, then `Collections` will just be null, which is perfectly fine at this point. If you're editing an existing TracksModel, then you shouldn't be saving the postback directly, anyways, but rather mapping the posted data back onto the entity pulled fresh from the database. For example:

```
var tracks = db.Tracks.Find(model.TrackId);
tracks.TrackName = model.TrackName;
tracks.TrackDescription = model.TrackDescription;
db.Entry(tracks).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Whatever `Collections` was, then, stays just as it was with no changes.

Comment: I am just creating new tracks, however the tracksmodel appears null  in the controller so I can't add it to the database.

Comment: Are you posting via AJAX? If so, then include your AJAX code, because that seems to be where your problem is.

Comment: Added the JavaScript I am using to post.  Also almost this exact code is being used on another modal window and that is working fine, which is why I am thinking I might need to separate all my models out into separate models instead of daisy chaining with base classes like I am doing now.

Comment: Just wanted to give this one last bump before redesigning the model to see if I could learn what was causing this issue.